# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've seen a few of these questions asked but haven't spotted one that's helped!! I'm trying to select the first part of a postcode only, essentially ignoring anything after the space. the code I am using is

```
SUBSTRING(PostCode, 1 , CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1)
```

However, I am getting:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

There's no nulls or blanks but there are some the only have the first part. Is this what causing the error and if so what's the work around?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That would only happen if `PostCode` is missing a space.
You could add conditionality such that all of `PostCode` is retrieved should a space not be found as follows

```
select SUBSTRING(PostCode, 1 ,
case when  CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) = 0 then LEN(PostCode) 
else CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode) -1 end)
```

Answer (score 29):

`CHARINDEX` will return `0` if no spaces are in the string and then you look for a substring of `-1` length.

You can tack a trailing space on to the end of the string to ensure there is always at least one space and avoid this problem.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(PostCode, 1 , CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode + ' ' ) -1)
```

Answer (score 11):

This is because the **CHARINDEX-1** is returning a -ive value if the look-up for " " (space) is 0. The simplest solution would be to avoid **'-ve**' by adding

`ABS(CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1))`

which will return only +ive values for your length even if `CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1)` is a -ve value. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Please explain in what cases CHARINDEX is negative

Comment: @fjuan - it is not uncommon to use len(field)-1. In some cases len(field) is 0 and then will be -1 causing an error in some function like Left() or Substring()

Comment: @Kairan this avoids an error but how does it help return the correct results? In the event the postcode contains no space converting minus one to positive one means that it will just return the first character if used as `SELECT SUBSTRING(PostCode,1,ABS(CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1))` (I'd imagine the desired correct results would be either return the entire original string or an empty string but not that)

Answer (score 1):

One of the selected column is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it might help someone. Based on my experience and trying to use some solution posted here saying that it might be a NULL causing the error.
In my case it was not NULL, I got the result of a Sigle digit and the CHARINDEX Was not working. What I did I used the IIF statement to check if the results are 1 digit the I display them without as they are, then for more than 1 digits or float numbers, that's where I used the CHARINDEX and it worked. Thank you!

e.g
IIF(len(TotalWorkExperience) = 1, TotalWorkExperience, left(TotalWorkExperience, CHARINDEX('.', TotalWorkExperience) - 1))  as ExperienceYears,

Answer (score -1):

Something else you can use is `isnull`:

```
isnull( SUBSTRING(PostCode, 1 , CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1), PostCode)
```

Answer (score -1):

substirng always work from left to right. substring 3 argument shouldnt be -ve.here CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1 resulting -ve value.so hanndle with case statement.

case when CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) > 1
then NULL
else SUBSTRING(PostCode, 1 , CHARINDEX(' ', PostCode ) -1)