# tsql Avoid errors in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this (SQL server):

```
UPDATE TableX set FieldB = 'SomeValue'  
where
FieldA is not null and FieldC is not NULL and FieldB is null and FieldD > 0 and
substring(FieldA,5, CHARINDEX('/', FieldA, 5) - 5) in ('ValueA','ValueB')
```

The problem is that sometimes `FieldA` is null and this query fails on the first occurrence of null on `FieldA`, I don't want that.

The error message is:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

And it caused by `FieldA` being null.

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368062/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substring-function

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl that solution is about a select clause not a where clause

Comment: @jean could you provide and example ??

Comment: Sorry, someone started to talk to me and I missed something, took FieldA for a variable. Anyway you problem is **FieldA is null** and the substring expression are evaluated at the same time. In that case I can just use coalesce to prevent FieldA to supply a null to the expression and be sure it beahves in the predicted way.

Comment: `SELECT substring(FieldA,5, ABS(CHARINDEX('/', ISNULL(FieldA,''), 5) - 5)) FROM TABLEX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wrap that final clause in parentheses and allow for the value to be `NULL`, something like this;

```
UPDATE TableX 
set FieldB = 'SomeValue'  
where
FieldA is not null 
and FieldC is not NULL 
and FieldB is null 
and FieldD > 0 
and
(
substring(FieldA,5, CHARINDEX('/', FieldA, 5) - 5) in ('ValueA','ValueB')
OR
FieldA IS NULL
)
```

If you're still having issues with `NULL` then it may be because your `CHARINDEX` can possibly return a negative number (if it doesn't find a '/' in your data). Provide some sample data and you'll get additional answers. Try the query below which uses the `ABS()` function;

```
UPDATE TableX 
set FieldB = 'SomeValue'  
where
FieldA is not null 
and FieldC is not NULL 
and FieldB is null 
and FieldD > 0 
and
(
substring(FieldA,5, ABS(CHARINDEX('/', ISNULL(FieldA,''), 5) - 5)) in ('ValueA','ValueB')
OR
FieldA IS NULL
)
```

Comment: your solution still raises the error because it doesn't handle the case when FieldA is null on the substring fucntion.

Comment: Try the second one with the ISNULL that I've just added. Sample data would allow for this to be tested properly. If you still have an issue then please add sample data to your question.

Comment: `SELECT substring(FieldA,5, ABS(CHARINDEX('/', ISNULL(FieldA,''), 5) - 5)) FROM TABLEX`works fine , so I guess it is a solution !! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to coalesce `FieldA` to a dummy string in the event that it be `NULL`:

```
UPDATE TableX
SET FieldB = 'SomeValue'  
WHERE FieldA IS NOT NULL AND
      FieldC IS NOT NULL AND
      FieldB IS NULL AND
      FieldD > 0 AND
      SUBSTRING(COALESCE(FieldA, '          /'),
                5,
                CHARINDEX('/', COALESCE(FieldA, '          /'), 5) - 5) 
          IN ('ValueA','ValueB')
```

The dummy string I used is ten spaces followed by a forward slash, i.e. `__________/`

Now when `FieldA` be `NULL` either the `IS NULL` check will be hit first, or the substring condition will be hit first.  In both cases, the `WHERE` check would fail for `NULL` `FieldA`.

Comment: I like this but it still raises the error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my query exactly?

Comment: Try running this query: `SELECT SUBSTRING(COALESCE(FieldA, '     /'), 5, CHARINDEX('/', COALESCE(FieldA, '     /'), 5) - 5) FROM TableX` ... do you get an error?

Comment: You absolutely need five or more spaces with a forward slash at the end in the `COALESCE` in order for the trick to work.

Comment: I tried the select statement but it still raises the same error and (I added the spaced and the forward slash)

Comment: Sorry I see the problem.  Updating now.