# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function in my query

Tags: sql-server

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

This is my sql query:-

```
select isnull(max(CAST(substring(assetid,patindex('%-%',assetid)+1,100)+1 AS INTEGER)),1) 
from hardware_register 
where substring(assetid,1,patindex('%-%', assetid)-1) = upper('ACS')
```

Comment: Can you show us sample table data?  We don't know what you are trying to do here.

Comment: it fails on `assetid` that does not have "-" in it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368062/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substring-function)

Answer (score 0):

if "-" not present in assetid or there are no records satisfying your query you will have this error.

Do check if "-" present in assetid and then pass the lenght.

```
select isnull(max(CAST(substring(assetid,CASE WHEN (patindex('%-%',assetid)>0) THEN patindex('%-%',assetid)+1 END,100)+1 AS INTEGER)),1) 
from hardware_register
```

Please validate the SQL and change in where clause also.