# SUBSTRING expression works in FROM clause but fails in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2019, I've got this SQL query that works. The second column returned is a hack to get the associated user name that isn't stored elsewhere in this system log. All rows with the Web_Unauthorized event type are of the form:

> Unauthorized attempt from account [user name] to access [url requested]

```
SELECT
    SystemLog.Id AS SystemLogId,
    SUBSTRING(SystemLog.Message,
        LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') + 2,
        PATINDEX('%to access%', SystemLog.Message) - LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') - 3
    ) AS UserName,
    SystemLog.Timestamp AS ServerTime,
    SystemLog.Message
FROM
    SystemLog
WHERE
    EventType = 'Web_Unauthorized'
```

But I want to exclude rows where the user name is FOO. So I tried the following, which is identical except for the addition of a second test to the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    SystemLog.Id AS SystemLogId,
    SUBSTRING(SystemLog.Message,
        LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') + 2,
        PATINDEX('%to access%', SystemLog.Message) - LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') - 3
    ) AS UserName,
    SystemLog.Timestamp AS ServerTime,
    SystemLog.Message
FROM
    SystemLog
WHERE
    EventType = 'Web_Unauthorized'
    AND SUBSTRING(SystemLog.Message,
        LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') + 2,
        PATINDEX('%to access%', SystemLog.Message) - LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') - 3
    ) <> 'FOO'
```

When I execute this in SSMS, four rows are displayed before SSMS flips me to the Messages pane where it displays the error message:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But the `SUBSTRING` call I'm making in the WHERE clause is the same one the worked in the FROM clause. Why is it failing in the WHERE clause?

I tried this as well, but with the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    SystemLog.Id AS SystemLogId,
    SUBSTRING(SystemLog.Message,
        LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') + 2,
        PATINDEX('%to access%', SystemLog.Message) - LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') - 3
    ) AS UserName,
    SystemLog.Timestamp AS ServerTime,
    SystemLog.Message
FROM
    SystemLog
WHERE
    EventType = 'Web_Unauthorized'
) Main
    WHERE Main.UserName <> 'FOO'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368062/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substring-function), and because in the WHERE clause ALL records are checked (to check if the where is OK), and in the SELECT only those that pass the WHERE clause.

Comment: As to why you get the error in the `WHERE` clause but not the `SELECT` clause, it depends on the execution plan. With the `WHERE` clause, the operator encountering the invalid length expression is evaluated before the EventType predicate. Without it, the rows are filtered before the same expression is evaluated for the `SELECT`. You'll get the same error if you remove the `WHERE` entirely.

Comment: It's likely your patindex returns a 0 for some rows, making the value negative. You could wrap a case around it: case when > 0 then patindex -2 else 0 end

Comment: I'd run the original query with the PATINDEX call itself added as a column in the FROM clause, and the data that appeared were all positive integers. That's why I tried the nested query, figuring that the outer query would see only the rows returned by the inner query.

Comment: `WHERE` clauses may well be applied against more rows than are returned, depending on how SQL Server chooses to retrieve the data. This is a very common problem and is solved as suggested by using a case expression.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess the bottom line is that SQL Server thinks it's being clever with its optimizations when it's really causing trouble.

Comment: Well you have made a difficult problem for SQL Server, because any time you use any sort of function in the `WHERE` clause you prevent it from using indexes. So general principle is to avoid functions in the `where` clause at all costs... because you do shoot yourself in the foot from a performance perspective.

Comment: Dale K, would making it a persistent computed column do the trick? Then I could index it.

Comment: It would probably help, you would of course need to use the `case` version in your computed column because you know for sure that not every column will have that data in it.

Comment: The whole idea of SQL is that you specify the end result and the engine is allowed to get to this result in any way it wants. Conceptually, everything happens all at once. You are assuming that the expression EventType = 'Web_Unauthorized' is evaluated before the "SUBSTRING" expression. That is something you cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the SUBSTRING expression only evaluates rows where EventType is Web_Unauthorized.

Your extra check doesn't require the big pattern matching, so you could write this instead:

```
    SELECT SystemLog.Id AS SystemLogId,
    SUBSTRING(SystemLog.Message,
        LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') + 2,
        PATINDEX('%to access%', SystemLog.Message) - 
        LEN('Unauthorized attempt from account') - 3
    ) AS UserName,
    SystemLog.Timestamp AS ServerTime,
    SystemLog.Message
FROM
    SystemLog
WHERE
    EventType = 'Web_Unauthorized'
    AND SystemLog.Message NOT LIKE 'Unauthorized attempt from account _FOO_ to access%'
```